# How to get other objects in a Mongodb ArrayList with Java?

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to get the boolean's in each category of FACTION_ROLES. the faction_roles is an ArrayList and so it cannot be casted to a document. Therefore the following code wont work. I have tried a few things but have been stuck for hours. anyone have suggestions?

java:

```
Document appendDoc = doc.get("FACTION_ROLES", Document.class).get("RECRUIT", Document.class);
        boolean setFactionOpen = appendDoc.getBoolean("SET_FACTION_OPEN");
```

document:

```
"FACTION_ROLES": [{ <- arraylist
        "RECRUIT": { <- object
            "SET_FACTION_OPEN": false,
            "DISBAND_FACTION": false,
            "BUY_FACTION_UPGRADES": false,
            "BUY_FACTION_POINTS": false,
            "SET_MEMBER_TITLES": false,
            "SET_ENEMIES": false,
            "SET_ALLIES": false,
            "SET_NEUTRALS": false,
            "INVITE_MEMBERS": false,
            "KICK_MEMBERS": false,
            "PROMOTE_MEMBERS": false,
            "DEMOTE_MEMBERS": false,
            "DEPOSIT_MONEY": false,
            "WITHDRAW_MONEY": false,
            "SET_WARPS": false,
            "REMOVE_WARPS": false,
            "SET_MOTD": false,
            "SET_ANNOUNCEMENT": false,
            "EDIT_PERMISSIONS": false,
            "EDIT_ROLES": false,
            "SET_TAG": false,
            "COLLECTION_BIN": false,
            "FACTION_LOGS": false
        }
    }, {
        "MOD": {
            "SET_FACTION_OPEN": false,
            "DISBAND_FACTION": false,
            "BUY_FACTION_UPGRADES": false,
            "BUY_FACTION_POINTS": false,
            "SET_MEMBER_TITLES": false,
            "SET_ENEMIES": false,
            "SET_ALLIES": false,
            "SET_NEUTRALS": false,
            "INVITE_MEMBERS": false,
            "KICK_MEMBERS": false,
            "PROMOTE_MEMBERS": false,
            "DEMOTE_MEMBERS": false,
            "DEPOSIT_MONEY": false,
            "WITHDRAW_MONEY": false,
            "SET_WARPS": false,
            "REMOVE_WARPS": false,
            "SET_MOTD": false,
            "SET_ANNOUNCEMENT": false,
            "EDIT_PERMISSIONS": false,
            "EDIT_ROLES": false,
            "SET_TAG": false,
            "COLLECTION_BIN": false,
            "FACTION_LOGS": false
        }
```

Comment: I am unclear as to your objective.  Are you trying to query for a specific attribute, or are you trying to parse an entire document received by a query?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are after...

```
package test.barry;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        com.mongodb.client.MongoClient client = connectToReplicaSet();
        com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase("barrydb");
        com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection<org.bson.Document> collection = db.getCollection("collection");

        com.mongodb.client.FindIterable<org.bson.Document> iterable1 = collection.find(new org.bson.BsonDocument());

        // AUTO-CLOSABLE TRY
        try(com.mongodb.client.MongoCursor<org.bson.Document> cursor1 = iterable1.iterator())
        {
            while (cursor1.hasNext())
            {
                org.bson.Document queriedDocument1 = cursor1.next();
                System.out.println(String.format("queriedDocument1: %s", queriedDocument1));

                java.util.List<org.bson.Document> factionRoles = (java.util.ArrayList<org.bson.Document> )queriedDocument1.get("FACTION_ROLES");

                for(org.bson.Document factionRole: factionRoles)
                {
                    java.util.Set<String> keyset1 = factionRole.keySet();

                    for (String key1: keyset1)
                    {
                        org.bson.Document key1Document = (org.bson.Document)factionRole.get(key1);

                        java.util.Set<String> keyset2 = key1Document.keySet();

                        for (String key2: keyset2)
                        {
                            System.out.println(String.format("%s.%s = %s", key1, key2, key1Document.get(key2)));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static com.mongodb.client.MongoClient connectToReplicaSet() {
        java.util.ArrayList<com.mongodb.ServerAddress> hosts = new java.util.ArrayList<com.mongodb.ServerAddress>();
        hosts.add(new com.mongodb.ServerAddress("localhost", 42011));
        hosts.add(new com.mongodb.ServerAddress("localhost", 42012));
        hosts.add(new com.mongodb.ServerAddress("localhost", 42013));

        com.mongodb.MongoCredential mongoCredential = com.mongodb.MongoCredential.createScramSha256Credential("testuser", "admin", "mysecret".toCharArray());

        com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettings = com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings.builder()
            .applyToClusterSettings(clusterSettingsBuilder -> clusterSettingsBuilder.hosts(hosts).requiredReplicaSetName("replSet"))
            .credential(mongoCredential)
            .writeConcern(com.mongodb.WriteConcern.MAJORITY)
            .readConcern(com.mongodb.ReadConcern.MAJORITY)
            .readPreference(com.mongodb.ReadPreference.primary())
            .retryWrites(true)
            .build();

        com.mongodb.client.MongoClient client = com.mongodb.client.MongoClients.create(mongoClientSettings);

        return client;
    }
}
```

Produces the following output...

```
RECRUIT.SET_FACTION_OPEN = false
RECRUIT.DISBAND_FACTION = false
RECRUIT.BUY_FACTION_UPGRADES = false
RECRUIT.BUY_FACTION_POINTS = false
RECRUIT.SET_MEMBER_TITLES = false
RECRUIT.SET_ENEMIES = false
RECRUIT.SET_ALLIES = false
RECRUIT.SET_NEUTRALS = false
RECRUIT.INVITE_MEMBERS = false
RECRUIT.KICK_MEMBERS = false
RECRUIT.PROMOTE_MEMBERS = false
RECRUIT.DEMOTE_MEMBERS = false
RECRUIT.DEPOSIT_MONEY = false
RECRUIT.WITHDRAW_MONEY = false
RECRUIT.SET_WARPS = false
RECRUIT.REMOVE_WARPS = false
RECRUIT.SET_MOTD = false
RECRUIT.SET_ANNOUNCEMENT = false
RECRUIT.EDIT_PERMISSIONS = false
RECRUIT.EDIT_ROLES = false
RECRUIT.SET_TAG = false
RECRUIT.COLLECTION_BIN = false
RECRUIT.FACTION_LOGS = false
MOD.SET_FACTION_OPEN = false
MOD.DISBAND_FACTION = false
MOD.BUY_FACTION_UPGRADES = false
MOD.BUY_FACTION_POINTS = false
MOD.SET_MEMBER_TITLES = false
MOD.SET_ENEMIES = false
MOD.SET_ALLIES = false
MOD.SET_NEUTRALS = false
MOD.INVITE_MEMBERS = false
MOD.KICK_MEMBERS = false
MOD.PROMOTE_MEMBERS = false
MOD.DEMOTE_MEMBERS = false
MOD.DEPOSIT_MONEY = false
MOD.WITHDRAW_MONEY = false
MOD.SET_WARPS = false
MOD.REMOVE_WARPS = false
MOD.SET_MOTD = false
MOD.SET_ANNOUNCEMENT = false
MOD.EDIT_PERMISSIONS = false
MOD.EDIT_ROLES = false
MOD.SET_TAG = false
MOD.COLLECTION_BIN = false
MOD.FACTION_LOGS = false
```

By the way, your sample document in your posted question is broken and does not import without some triage.  For people trying to help it is worthwhile ensuring your sample code is clean.  Help me help you.

For others wishing to repeat this code example, here is a document in the database I tested with...

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60d62d3d9148371ae7d2b34d"),
    "FACTION_ROLES" : [
        {
            "RECRUIT" : {
                "SET_FACTION_OPEN" : false,
                "DISBAND_FACTION" : false,
                "BUY_FACTION_UPGRADES" : false,
                "BUY_FACTION_POINTS" : false,
                "SET_MEMBER_TITLES" : false,
                "SET_ENEMIES" : false,
                "SET_ALLIES" : false,
                "SET_NEUTRALS" : false,
                "INVITE_MEMBERS" : false,
                "KICK_MEMBERS" : false,
                "PROMOTE_MEMBERS" : false,
                "DEMOTE_MEMBERS" : false,
                "DEPOSIT_MONEY" : false,
                "WITHDRAW_MONEY" : false,
                "SET_WARPS" : false,
                "REMOVE_WARPS" : false,
                "SET_MOTD" : false,
                "SET_ANNOUNCEMENT" : false,
                "EDIT_PERMISSIONS" : false,
                "EDIT_ROLES" : false,
                "SET_TAG" : false,
                "COLLECTION_BIN" : false,
                "FACTION_LOGS" : false
            }
        },
        {
            "MOD" : {
                "SET_FACTION_OPEN" : false,
                "DISBAND_FACTION" : false,
                "BUY_FACTION_UPGRADES" : false,
                "BUY_FACTION_POINTS" : false,
                "SET_MEMBER_TITLES" : false,
                "SET_ENEMIES" : false,
                "SET_ALLIES" : false,
                "SET_NEUTRALS" : false,
                "INVITE_MEMBERS" : false,
                "KICK_MEMBERS" : false,
                "PROMOTE_MEMBERS" : false,
                "DEMOTE_MEMBERS" : false,
                "DEPOSIT_MONEY" : false,
                "WITHDRAW_MONEY" : false,
                "SET_WARPS" : false,
                "REMOVE_WARPS" : false,
                "SET_MOTD" : false,
                "SET_ANNOUNCEMENT" : false,
                "EDIT_PERMISSIONS" : false,
                "EDIT_ROLES" : false,
                "SET_TAG" : false,
                "COLLECTION_BIN" : false,
                "FACTION_LOGS" : false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```